# scrlttr2: Position of the recipient's address

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

I have `scrlttr2` based letter with source code given below.

The letter will be printed on a windowed enveloped and I need to specify the exact location of the recipient's address box.

How can I do this (make the recipient's address box appear at a certain location on the paper) ?

```
% koma_env.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,backaddress=off,foldmarks=false,fromalign=right]{scrlttr2}
% \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[english]{babel}
% \usepackage{url}

\setkomavar{date}{\flushleft\vspace{-\baselineskip}\today\par}

\setkomavar{fromname}{\{\{Landlord Name\}\}}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\{\{Landlord Correspondence Address Line 1\} \\ \{\{Landlord Correspondence Line 2 (if applicable)\}\} \\ \{\{Town/City\}\} \\ \{\{County\}\} \\ \{\{Postcode\}\}}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{\{\{Tenant Names\}\} \\ \{\{Property Address Line 1\}\} \\ \{\{Property Address Line 2 (if applicable)\}\}
\\ \{\{Town/City\}\} \\ \{\{County\}\} \\ \{\{Postcode\}\}}

\KOMAoptions{fromphone=false,fromfax=false}
\setkomavar{subject}{Pre Check-Out Inspection at \{\{1st line of Property\}\}}

\opening{Dear \{\{Tenant Names\}\}}

Your tenancy is due to come to an end on \{\{date\}\}. I would like to arrange an inspection at the property before the tenancy ends to identify anything that may lead me to retain some of your deposit if not addressed by the time I retake possession.

Carrying out this inspection prior to the tenancy ending will give you the opportunity to tackle anything raised and ensure I can return the maximum amount of deposit to you when the tenancy ends

I would like to carry out the inspection on \{\{date\}\} at \{\{time\}\}. It would be best if you were present then if anything is identified we can discuss this and be clear on what would be required to rectify it. Please can you contact me as soon as possible to confirm whether or not this is convenient.

If you do not wish to be present I have a set of keys to access the property and will send you the results of the inspection. Please let me know either way at your earliest convenience.

\closing{Kind Regards}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: scrlettr2 has different paper formats you can choose of. For example german DIN is the standard, making the letter (and the address window) fit the german standardised envelopes. This LOCALE information might be helpful in your case.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks. Is it possible to specify the location of the address box in terms like "x cm from the top, y cm from the left"?

Answer (score 11):

You can change the KOMA pseudolengths `toaddrhpos` (distance from left) and `toaddrvpos`. The height and the width of the address box can be defined by the pseudolengths `toaddrheight` and `toaddrwidth`.

To get a frame around the address box you can load the `visualize.lco` and say `\showfields{address}`

```
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}% loads visualize.lco to visualize boxes
\showfields{address}% show the address box

\makeatletter
  \@setplength{backaddrheight}{0pt}% because backaddress=off
  \@setplength{toaddrhpos}{2.5cm}%distance from left
  \@setplength{toaddrvpos}{5cm}%distance from top
  \@setplength{toaddrheight}{3.5cm}%height of the addressbox
  \@setplength{toaddrwidth}{10cm}% width of the addressbox
\makeatother
```

**Update**

Since KOMA-Script version 3.26 scrlttr2 provides also `\setplength` (without the `@`). Using `\setplength` the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` can be removed:

```latex
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}% loads visualize.lco to visualize boxes
\showfields{address}% show the address box

\setplength{backaddrheight}{0pt}% because backaddress=off
\setplength{toaddrhpos}{2.5cm}%distance from left
\setplength{toaddrvpos}{5cm}%distance from top
\setplength{toaddrheight}{3.5cm}%height of the addressbox
\setplength{toaddrwidth}{10cm}% width of the addressbox
```

Additional remark: Do not use the variable `date` to align the date left. Therefore you can use option:

```latex
refline=dateleft
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

KOMA-Script has so called pseudo lengths to define locations on the note paper. See `toaddrhpos` and `toaddrvpos` in section "21.1. Pseudo-Lengths for Experienced Users" and figure 21.1 of the [KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf).